# Anyone know when the next version of Crystal Reports is coming out?

Tags: crystal-reports

I already know that BO was bought up by SAP on the cheap, but it's been 2 years since CR2008 came out.  I'm asking because we need to buy a license for a 2nd machine and I don't want to submit a second purchase order to my boss 2 months later for the next version of Crystal.

Comment: Any answer you got on this in 2010 would be useless for someone asking the question now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe anything has been mentioned publicly yet, other than the version for Visual Studio 2010 (which is not higher than 2008).

Buy 2008. There's not reason to immediately buy any new versions of Crystal Reports anyway. The new versions are always buggy out-of-the-gate.